# How can I reset the NVRAM, PRAM, and SMC of a MacBook a1534 from 2017 if the keyboard doesn't work?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, hardware

How can I reset the PRAM, NVRAM, SMC if the keyboard doesn't work and I cannot boot into Sierra (it is in a continuous boot loop probably from the NVRAM).

Comment: Try doing an external USB or Bluetooth Keyboard

Comment: ya, thats the other problem, i can't boot into sierra

Comment: the macbook wont recognize key presses from the external keyboard while the apple logo is on, and then it just reboots and doesn't boot sierra

Comment: Does every single Key malfunction? Also, if you can boot macOS Single User mode (Command + S during startup), then you can try ```nvram -c``` and then ```sudo reboot```.

Comment: yea the whole keyboard seems unresponsive

Comment: the external keyboard works except the macbook startup commands are ignored

Comment: Well, I guess the Mac is gone. If you can boot Single User mode (Command+S), then you can try ```nvram -c```. Try using an Apple USB Keyboard made by Apple such as the one that comes with iMacs.